# Grid View Check Box Hide When Sub Total Show

Tags: asp.net

I have To Grid View (Nested Grid View).When I Show Sum Of Total In Child Grid View 
Group BY Qualityid Than Extra Check Box Create In a Row  Where Total Show.How To Hide This Check Box .

This Is My Code
Code Behind (.CS Page)

```
ds = obj.GetDataSet(query);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var groupbyqname = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("Qualityid"));
            foreach (var group in groupbyqname)
            {
                decimal qty = 0;
                decimal qty1 = 0;

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if ( Convert.ToInt32(dr["Qualityid"].ToString()) == group.Key)
                    {
                         qty += Convert.ToDecimal(dr["ReceiveQty"].ToString());
                         qty1 += Convert.ToDecimal(dr["ActualQty"].ToString());
                         dt.ImportRow(dr);
                    }
                }
                DataRow drSummary = dt.NewRow();
                drSummary["Remark"] = "<span style='font-weight: 700;color:#c75656;'>Total:" + group.Key + "</span>";
                // drSummary["ReceiveQty"] =  " " + qty  + "";
                // drSummary["ActualQty"] = "" + qty1 + "" ;
                drSummary["UnitName"] = "<span style='font-weight: 700;color:#c75656;'> " + Convert.ToString(qty1) + "</span>&nbsp<span style='font-weight: 700;color:#c75656;'> kG</span>";
                drSummary["UnitName1"] = "<span style='font-weight: 700;color:#c75656;'> " + Convert.ToString(qty) + "</span>&nbsp<span style='font-weight: 700;color:#c75656;'> kG</span>";
                dt.Rows.Add(drSummary);
            }

            gvOrders.DataSource = dt;
            gvOrders.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

[image]

How To Solve Please Help Me.